# UPDATE Multiple Records based on Multiple values returned

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update

I have the following Table called Player_MVP_Month which is linked to my Player table.

[Here is the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imapm.jpg)

I would like to update the MVP for October 2015. There could be multiple MVPs for each month, which is the case for October 2015. A player is MVP based on the number of times he's scored a winning goal in a given month.
I had no problem in updating December because only one player had the MAX COUNT, but for October 6 players have the exact same count. Therefore I would like to have my 6 player IDs updated during October.
How could I do this ?

Here is what I have for the moment:

```
UPDATE PLAYER_MVP_MONTH
SET    Player_ID = (
   SELECT Player.Player_ID
   FROM Game JOIN Player ON Game.Winning_Goal = Player.Player_ID
   WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-10-2015' AND '30-10-2015'
   GROUP BY Player.Player_ID
   HAVING COUNT(Winning_Goal) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(Winning_Goal))
                                 FROM Game
                                 WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-10-2015' AND '30-10-2015'
                                 GROUP BY Winning_Goal))
WHERE PLAYER_MVP_MONTH.MVP_DATE = 'October 2015';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you very much.

Sorry for posting a link instead of the image but apparently I need 10 reputations to post images.

I tried

`MERGE INTO PLAYER_MVP_MONTH
  USING (SELECT Player.Player_ID
       FROM Game JOIN Player ON Game.Winning_Goal = Player.Player_ID
       WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-11-2015' AND '30-11-2015'
       GROUP BY Player.Player_ID
       HAVING COUNT(Winning_Goal) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(Winning_Goal))
                                     FROM Game
                                     WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-11-2015' AND '30-11-2015'
                                     GROUP BY Winning_Goal))
  ON (Player.PLAYER_ID = PLAYER_MVP_MONTH.Player_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET PLAYER_MVP_MONTH.Player_ID = Player.Player_ID ;`

Anybody has any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `MERGE` command here which will update or insert data based on the criteria provided.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

---

UPDATE 1: Your new `MERGE` statement is missing a `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT` clause which will add the additional rows to the `PLAYER_MVP_MONTH` table for the other players that have the same number of goals.

It would be something like this:

```
MERGE INTO PLAYER_MVP_MONTH
  USING (SELECT Player.Player_ID
       FROM Game JOIN Player ON Game.Winning_Goal = Player.Player_ID
       WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-11-2015' AND '30-11-2015'
       GROUP BY Player.Player_ID
       HAVING COUNT(Winning_Goal) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(Winning_Goal))
                                     FROM Game
                                     WHERE Game_Date BETWEEN '01-11-2015' AND '30-11-2015'
                                     GROUP BY Winning_Goal))
  ON (Player.PLAYER_ID = PLAYER_MVP_MONTH.Player_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET PLAYER_MVP_MONTH.Player_ID = Player.Player_ID
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO PLAYER_MVP_MONTH (MVP_DATE, PLAYER_ID) VALUES ('01-11-2015', Player.Player_ID);
```